# How is this Solenoid made?

Tags: electromagnetism, actuator

I ran into this old YouTube video. As you can see apparently it's a solenoid, but the person doesn't explain how it's made. I've never seen a solenoid with such a long stroke, if you can please explain in detail as I'd like to make one myself. [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKgRCIarczo&ab_channel=rolfel)

Comment: looks fake ... the pipes probably have a slit on back side ... some type of a pulley system may be at work ... there is a sound of a hard stop at exactly the same place

Comment: @jsotola If it is a fake, it's done well.  Look how the hands move in the second clip, the .  I expect the hard stop is because of the bar that keeps the two pipes separated.  I think it is not a fake ... but there's a lot going on we don't see.

Comment: @user1683793 the other possibility is that the device uses wheels to travel along the pipe and the sound is produced by a brake ... the brake possibly uses an electromagnet to clamp onto the pipe

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue but observe that,

1. There are two pipes that look like regular water pipes.
2. The pipes are held apart from each other.
3. The description says "simple DC magnet."
4. There is a rectangular box attached to the slider that moves on the pipes.

I will speculate that the pipes have stacked magnets inside which causes each pipe to be a long, strong magnet.  If the north pole of one were paired with the south pole of the other, they would need to be held apart (as we see).  If the coil were contained in the box attached to the slider and set up so the end closest to the pipe was on pole (with the other pole farther away), when energized with DC voltage, they would be repelled from one end and attracted to the other (I think).  In the third case, the current is variable and just high enough to repel the coil from that end.

Would that actually work?  I'd have to think about for a while before buying little magnets, water pipe and coils that fit the pipe but on the basis of SWAG speculation, I'll say that's how it works.

Comment: There is no need for stacked magnets inside the poles. The poles just need to be ferromagnetic, like iron.

Comment: @RC_23  Quite so, No need for stacked magnets inside, just for he pipes to be quite strong magnets and I don't see that happening by trying to magnetize the pipes.

Comment: No, my understanding is the pipes do not need to permanent magnets at all.  They just need to be ferromagnetic, usually iron and copper mixture